# Return the first letter of each sentence in a string

Tags: php

I'm not sure where to start with this one but I'm hoping someone can help.

When a user submits a message I want to check the string and return the first letter of each sentence and place it into an array. Basically I want the first letter in the string and every letter immediately after a full stop (if there are any) placed in an array.

Has anyone ever done this in the past? Is it even possible?

Hoping you can help

Cj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string in sentences - use `explode()` or `preg_split()` with the punctiation mark. Then loop all sentences an get the first letter using `mb_substr($sentence, 0, 1);` Don't forget to trim all senteces from whitespaces at the start or end of sentence.

Comment: Hi that's great cheers. As a quick question how would you trim the whitespaces? I cant think of an obvious way to do it.... P.s. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Legend! thank you I think I got that working... I was trying to write something connected with a student project to tell people off if they didn't use capitals (just for a little humour).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like:

```
preg_match_all("/\b\w/", $yourString, $matches);
```

And then $matches will contain an array with an entry for every one of the characters your are looking for.